# using .gsub to double quotes and punctuation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gsub

I am trying to remove all double-quoted quotations in a string:

For example: "Mary said "Lookout"!?"

"Mary said "Lookout"!?" is coming from a html form with a textarea tag

```
     <textarea id="receiver" name="receiver" class="form-control"  maxlength= "1080" type="text"></textarea>
```

That is then put into a variable called Words. So:

```
Words = "Mary said "Lookout"!?"
```

Then I run

```
Words.gsub!(/[!?/A"|"/Z]/, "")
```

I want the output to read:

```
Mary said Lookout
```

Instead I am getting an error,

```
"Mary said "Lookout"!?".gsub!(/[!?/A"|"/Z]/, "")
 SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input "Mary said "Lookout"!?".gsub!(/[!?/A"|"/Z]/, "")
```

Comment: I should specify that the receiver in the method is from a html form. I believe Ruby will always set the string to double quotes.

Comment: Please share the receiver and form code

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you have not escaped the speech marks. Ruby doesn't understand more than two speech marks in a row unless you tell it they're meant to be there. Try this:

```
"Mary said \"Lookout\"!?"
```

I believe there is still an issue with your gsub as well. Try that first and see if you can get further on your own.

Comment: I should specify that the receiver in the method is from a form so I couldn't then add \ \ to the string.